# Solving equations of the form $c_0 \sin\left(x+p_0\right)+c_1\sin\left(2x+p_1\right)=0$

Tags: trigonometry, roots

How do I solve this equation?
$$c_0 \sin\left(x+p_0\right)+c_1\sin\left(2x\right)=0$$
where $c_0$, $p_0$, and $c_1$ are fixed constants? What about the more general form:

$$c_0 \sin\left(x+p_0\right)+c_1\sin\left(2x+p_1\right)=0$$

where $c_0$, $p_0$, $c_1$, and $p_1$ are constants?

Comment: What have you tried? Have you used the standard $\sin(a+b) = \sin(a)\cos(b)+\sin(b)\cos(a)$ identity to simplify? Also, since $c_0,c_1$ are arbitrary, you can divide the whole equation by $c_1$ to remove a coefficient. After expanding, you will have a quadratic in sin(x) which you can solve.

Comment: The "more general" form is not more general. By a shift of the unknown, you can get rid of $p_1$.

Answer (score 0):

WLOG, $c_1=1$.

The equation can be rewritten under the form

$$s \sin x+c\cos x+\sin x\cos x=0.$$

Then we use the substitution

$$\sin x=\frac{2t}{t^2+1},\cos x=\frac{t^2-1}{t^2+1}$$ 
and obtain the quartic equation

$$t^4+2\frac{s+1}ct^3+2\frac{s-1}ct-1=0.$$

I don't think that there will be a simplification in the expressions of the roots and you must solve this using the general formulas. There will be two or four real roots in $t$, i.e. an even number of roots per period, as was expected.

---

By the theory of quartic equations, the number of roots is two or four depending on the sign of the discriminant
$$-27(b^4+d^4)-4(bd)^3+6(bd)^2-192bd-256$$ where $b$ and $d$ are the cubic and linear coefficients above.

---

Letting $u:=\cos x$ and $v:=\sin x$, the given equation is that of an equilateral hyperbola, which passes through the origin,

$$(u+s)(v+c)=cs,$$ and we are intersecting it with the unit circle

$$u^2+v^2=1.$$

[image]

Comment: @ Yves Daoust  Elegant approach but concerning the number of solutions see my EDIT.

Comment: @Dr.WolfgangHintze: this rationalization approach is bulletproof, as it establishes a bijection between the real line and the unit circle (except for one point).

Comment: @Dr.WolfgangHintze: should I really explain how to solve the inequation $t^2>1$ ?

Comment: I don't quite understand your angry behaviour. Why don't you just admit that 3 roots are possible in a quartic, e.g. $f(x) = (x-a)(x-b)(x-c)^2$?

Comment: @Dr.WolfgangHintze: angry behavior ?? Of course there are limit cases between $2$ and $4$, precisely when the discriminant is zero.

Comment: @  Yves Daoust Ok, I was right and we are d'accord. I repeat with pleasure that I like your substitution approach.

Answer (score -1):

**Original post**

If either $c_0=0$ or $c_1=0$ (or both) the problem is trivial.

Hence we assume the opposite and let $a=\frac{c_1}{c_0}$. Furthermore we let $x=y-p_{1}/2$ and $q=p_{0}-p_{1}/2$. Then your generalized equation becomes

$$ \sin(y+q) + a \sin(2y) = 0\tag{1}$$

Since $\sin(y+q) = \sin(y) \cos(q) + \cos(y) \sin(q)$ and $\sin(2y) = 2 \sin(y) \cos(y)$  we get

$$ \sin(y) \cos(q) +  \cos(y) \sin(q) +  2 a \sin(y) \cos(y) = 0\tag{2}$$

Now letting $z = \sin(y)$ we have $\cos(y) = \sqrt{1-z^2}$ and $(2)$ becomes

$$ z \cos(q) +  \sqrt{1-z^2} \sin(q) +  2 a z \sqrt{1-z^2}  = 0\tag{3}$$

This results is an algebraic equation of 8th degree in $z$. But it depends only on $z^2$ so that it is 4th degree in $s=z^2$. Let the four solutions be $s_{k}$, $k=1..4$.

Then the solutions $y$ are given by $y_{k}= \arcsin(\sqrt{s_{k}})$, $k=1..4$

**EDIT**

Here are some plots of the LHS of $(1)$ for $x \in [0,2\pi)$ for randomly chosen parameters $q\in (0,2\pi)$ and $a\in(-2,2)$

[image]

There are 2 roots (figs. 6,8,9), 3 roots (two have merged into a double root, figs. 5 and 7), in all other cases there are 4 roots.

Comment: "8th degree in $z$ or 4th in $\sqrt{z}$" Shouldn't that be the other way round?

Comment: You are right. Corrected.

Comment: Your approach of the number of roots is wrong, as you dropped $\cos(y)=-\sqrt{1-z^2}$. The curves should be closed and perforce have an even number of roots. A periodic function has an even number of roots.

Comment: To the downvoter: please give a reason and reveal yourself.

Comment: @ Yves Daoust Thanks for the hint. Indeed I missed the negative square root. Hence I am back to my original statement of 4 roots. Will correct my text.

Comment: Two is also possible. Consider $3\cos(x)+\sin(2x)$ f.i.

Comment: See my corrected EDIT for cases of 2,3, and 4 roots.

Comment: Predicting the number of roots might be a tractable problem.

Comment: Maybe, but why then did you miss the case of 3 zeros?